# How to implement a compareTo( ) method for generic objects?

Tags: java, generics, compareto

I am stuck on defining the `compareTo` method for a generic class.

I have created a generic class `BinarySearchTree`:

```
public class BinarySearchTree<K extends Comparable<K>, V>{
    Node root;

    private class Node{
        K key;
        V value;
        Node left=null;
        Node right=null;

        public Node(K k, V v){ key=k; value=v; }
    }
    ...

   private int compareTo(K k){

   }
}
```

The `compareTo` method is to compare two instances of generic type `K`. If they are equal, return `zero`. If `this` is smaller than `k`, return `-1`, otherwise return `1`.

I use `equals()` to check if they are equal. However, I am stuck on the remaining comparisons.

Comment: Forget about generics --- they're gone by the time your code gets there.  You must examine the actual runtime type of the objects and base any decisions on that.

Comment: Why do you need to implement a `compareTo` method? If instances of `K` are comparable, you can just do `k.compareTo(anotherK)`.

Comment: @PaulBellora is it because `K` extends `Comparable<K>` in the code? How does this work?

Comment: Yes, `K extends Comparable<K>` means that `K` must be some type that implements `Comparable<K>`. So `K` could be `String` (which implements `Comparable<String>`) or `Integer` (which implements `Comparable<Integer>`) for example. We say `K` has an *upper bound* of `Comparable<K>`. More info on bounded type parameters: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html

Answer (score 1):

you should not compare a `Node<K>` with a `K`. If you need to do comparisons from the outside, why not just expose the `K` with a getter?